# class not found when using external class in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am struggling to include an external class the Laravel way.  I have a round-about way of doing this right now..

First I have a file `app/Http/Requests/Moneris/Moneris.php` with the following content:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests\Moneris;

class mpgTransaction {
/* stuff */
}
```

Then in `app/Http/Controllers/MyController.php`, I have the following content:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

require_once(str_replace("/MyController.php","/",__FILE__).'../Requests/Moneris/Moneris.php');
use App\Http\Requests\Moneris as mn;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $mpg = new mn\mpgTransaction();
    }
}
```

And this works fine.   But if I change the content of `MyController.php` to:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\Moneris\Moneris;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $mpg = new mpgTransaction();
    }
}
```

I get a 500 internal server error and the logs say `mpgTransaction` class could not be found.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

To follow [PSR-1 standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) you should name your class as `Moneris` instead of `mpgTransaction`. Also for the autoloader to work, you must have file name and class name match.

So the file `Moneris.php` should be.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests\Moneris;

class Moneris {
/* stuff */
}
```

In Laravel you don't use `require_once()`, use [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) to autoload, therefore you should remove it when you follow the autoloader rules, which i think you will when you rename the class.

Your final controller version can then be.

```
use App\Http\Requests\Moneris\Moneris;

public function index()
{
    $mpg = new Moneris();
}
```

Comment: oH thanks, the Moneris is actually the SDK that Moneris gave me, and it has about 15 other classes there all starting with lowercase.  I wonder if that will cause problems later on....

Comment: Found similar SDK's for that code and i'm sad to say that is way below industry standard for a package. Just use your first hack and don't try to fix to much :) or make the changes your self locally.

Answer (score 3):

There are three type of `namespace`

1. unqualified
2. qualified
3. fully qualified

In your first case,you include that file and `namespace` was `qualified namespace`- that's why it was work fine. But in your second case, you just violated the autoload standard [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

> The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in `.php`. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.

It will work fine,if you just give class name `Moneris` instead of `mpgTransaction` in your `Moneris.php` file.

**How to use `use`**

```
// Pre PHP 7 code
use some\namespace\ClassA;
use some\namespace\ClassB;
use some\namespace\ClassC as C;

use function some\namespace\fn_a;
use function some\namespace\fn_b;
use function some\namespace\fn_c;

use const some\namespace\ConstA;
use const some\namespace\ConstB;
use const some\namespace\ConstC;

// PHP 7+ code
use some\namespace\{ClassA, ClassB, ClassC as C};
use function some\namespace\{fn_a, fn_b, fn_c};
use const some\namespace\{ConstA, ConstB, ConstC};
```

> **Note**: Namespace names are case-insensitive.

**Important link**

[namespaces basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)

Comment: Thank you for explaining the different types of name spaces.  It will help me in future.  IN the mean time, I don't want to rename mpgTransaction to Moneris because mpgTransaction is just one of many classes in the file as part of the Moneris SDK that I downloaded.  I don't feel comfortable right now rewriting the SDK for Moneris.

Comment: than you might change `Moneris.php` file name to `MpgTransaction.php`